# In a Jakarta app, catch Servlet exceptions from a Filter by wrapping the filterChain.doFilter in a try catch

Tags: java, exception, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a Jakarta based app, that has a number of servlets and a common filter that sits in front of them all.

Some of the servlets may throw an exception and I'd like to handle it inside the filter using a `try .. catch`

But when an exception is thrown, I see the stack-trace pasted below even though I'm `catch`ing inside the filter.

Is there a way to gracefully handle the exception in this manner, preventing it from being logged?

`MyFilter.java`:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    try {

      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

      try {
      
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("error");
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`MyServlet.java`:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Oops");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Oops");
    }
}
```

Causes this exception to be logged:

```
Jun 22, 2022 9:28:16 P.M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyServlet] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Ooops
    at com.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
```

Answer (score -2):

There are two types of exception in Java: **checked exception** (for e.g. ClassNotFoundException, IOException, FileNotFoundException) and u**nchecked exception** (which is also known as **runtime exception**). RuntimeException belongs to unchecked exception. If you want to handle the Exception in try..catch, you might want to use/throw checked exception.

UPDATED:
Have you tried this? Unfortunately I couldn't test it
…

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException{
      throw new ServletException("Oops");
    }
```

...

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
      //handle the Exception gracefully
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. In fact you cannot add a `throws` custom checked exception to `doPost` or `doGet` methods since they implement a specific interface i.e `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`

Comment: You can :    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {...}

Comment: Even if I throw `ServletException`, how does this prevent the stacktrace that gets logged? `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [TerseUIM2RequestProcessor] threw exception ..` I still see the exception logged whether its a checked or unchecked exception

Comment: Yes, I tried the updated code sample, as mentioned in the previous comment